# Linear Programming: Purely linear formulation (LP) for the expression "if x > 0; y =0 / if y > 0; x=0" without binary variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a problem which often occurs in energy system modelling (modelling of storages) where charging of a storage system is not allowed to when it is discharging and vice versa.

Let `x` and `y` be continous positive decision variables that represent the charging/discharging power of the storage unit. Now I am trying to express the following logic in equations or inequalities:

```
if x > 0:
    y = 0
if y > 0:
    x = 0
```

I know this can be realized with binary variables via the following equations if `b` is a binary variable and `x_ub` and `y_ub` represent the respective upper bound of the variables:

```
x <= b * x_ub
y <= (1-b) * y_ub
```

This results in a mixed-integer linear programm (MILP) and of course induces all the properties of a MILP which lay in higher runtimes, other interpretations of the solution, ...

Another way to get a pure LP formulation is to work with (very low) costs that are attached to `x` and `y` so that only one of both variables is set to a positive value. But this also affects my objective, has other disadvantages as is is somewhat of a hotfix.

So here's my question: Is there any way to express the logic above (if/else) in a purely linear program (LP)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be expressed as an LP. Conceptually you're after the following constraints:
$x \geq 0, y \geq 0, xy=0$.

The third constraint isn't convex, so there's no way you could represent that in terms of LP constraints, since those can only define convex regions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which makes sense to me. But I am not sure if there might be some "alternative description" for the third constraint like there is for other non-linear situations (Big-M, ...).

Comment: Right - this would be trying to use convex approximations, and error cost terms.

Comment: Basically if you want to remove $xy=0$ you have to add a cost term. Something like $C|x-y|$ would work well if $x$ and $y$ are "symmetric", as it prevents increasing them both together and getting away from a x=0 or y=0 edge.

Comment: Or adding a cost term on $x+y$. In any case, you can't get away from changing your objective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I also had an idea similar to the `C|x-y|` one. But this would also require cost terms which affects the objective and in this special case the behaviour of the storage..

Comment: You really don't have much choice here. $xy=0$ stipulates orthogonal edges, while LP constraints give polyhedrons. Thus, if you wish to eliminate the constraint, you must have some cost which guides the result away from the interior of the polyhedron towards the edges.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help!